# Wagtail:How to have multiple types of admin

Tags: django, wagtail

I am making a blogging website using wagtail so we have multiple writers so I need that no one can see drafts of other users and only the superadmin can post the blogs but I can't find that setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Previewing and submitting pages for moderation
>
> The Save/Preview/Submit for moderation menu is always present at the bottom of the page edit/creation screen. The menu allows you to perform the following actions, dependent on whether you are an editor, moderator [...]

Source: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/editor_manual/new_pages/previewing_and_submitting_for_moderation.html

Editors (you call them writers) can submit for moderation. Moderators can publish. So this part of your requirements is built in. My advice is to create users for each type and play around to get a feeling for this workflow.

There is no (out of the box) way to show pages to their creators only. However, you can give groups access to parts of the page tree:

1. Go to a page in the admin.
2. Top right, click the Privacy setting. Public is the default.
3. Change to 'Private, accessible to users in specific groups'.
4. Choose a group.

Now only users in this group can edit this section. So this page and all it's child pages.

Default there are two groups: Editors and Moderators. You can create new groups via `/admin/groups/new/`. If you give each user it's own group, you have what you want. Their pages will live in their own part of the page tree though.

Note that when you create a group it is also possible to limit permissions per content type. So you can make a group of users responsible for content of a specific type.

Wagtail users, groups, permissions, workflows and privacy settings makes it possible to configure permissions in a fine grained way. This will be sufficient in most cases.

When you have a project requirement that is more demanding, you can always add some extra logic to meet your requirement. Python/Django/Wagtail is a flexible software stack. But before going there, I would advice you to see if the standard settings are sufficient. If not, you should describe your requirements in more detail.